# How to redirect when at a certain part of a web page?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is it possible to redirect to a different page when at a certain point in a web page? For example, You visit the site and scroll down and when you've reached a certain anchor, it redirects you to a different page. Is this possible? And if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code detects that the user has scrolled by the desired amount (e.g. [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460116/detecting-offset-of-an-element-on-scroll-in-javascript-jquery)), have a callback function that navigates like so `window.top.location.href='nextpage.htm';`

Note that many users may find this annoying, especially when using devices like tablets where scrolling may be accidental.